# Sort and Group duplicate nodes under a new node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to group duplicate nodes under a new node (in sorted order). This is my xml.

```
<NodeRoot>
    <NodeA>
        <NodeB>
            <NodeC>101</NodeC>
            <NodeC>102</NodeC>
            <NodeC>101</NodeC>
            <NodeC>104</NodeC>
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
    <NodeA>
        <NodeB>
            <NodeC>102</NodeC>
            <NodeC>103</NodeC>
            <NodeC>101</NodeC>
            <NodeC>102</NodeC>
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
</NodeRoot>
```

And this is what I want to achieve. Note that the duplicate NodeCs are first sorted and then grouped under a new NodeGroup node.

```
<NodeRoot>
    <NodeA>
        <NodeB>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>101</NodeC>
                <NodeC>101</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>102</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>104</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
    <NodeA>
        <NodeB>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>101</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>102</NodeC>
                <NodeC>102</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
            <NodeGroup>
                <NodeC>103</NodeC>
            </NodeGroup>
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
</NodeRoot>
```

This is my xslt (I have access to only xslt1)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeB">
        <NodeB>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NodeB[not(NodeC = preceding-sibling::NodeB/NodeC)]" mode="GroupC">
                    <xsl:sort select="NodeC" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
        </NodeB>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeB" mode="GroupC">
        <xsl:variable name="GC" select="NodeC"/>
        <NodeB>
            <NodeGroup>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NodeB[NodeC/text()=$GC]" mode="SameC" />
            </NodeGroup>
        </NodeB>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeC" mode="SameC">
        <xsl:copy-of select="NodeC"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is not grouping the duplicate NodeCs. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take that approach with the preceding siblings then you simply need to make sure you process the `NodeC` children:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeB">
        <NodeB>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NodeC[not(. = preceding-sibling::NodeC)]" mode="GroupC">
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
        </NodeB>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeC" mode="GroupC">
        <NodeGroup>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../NodeC[. = current()]"/>
        </NodeGroup>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The extra mode is not even needed that way.

Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is usually more efficient using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) although here you then would need a key that concatenates the generated id of the `NodeB` parent with the `NodeC` value to allow you to identify groups inside a subtree of a `NodeB`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="NodeC" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', .)"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeB">
        <NodeB>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NodeC[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', .))[1])]" mode="GroupC">
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
        </NodeB>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NodeC" mode="GroupC">
        <NodeGroup>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', .))"/>
        </NodeGroup>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried using Muenchian grouping but was not able to group NodeCs (based on value) within different NodeBs. In fact, I would love to do it in Muenchian grouping which I believe is more efficient.

Comment: Not sure what you meant to say "I do need a new node". I have added an example using Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Thanks for both solutions. I thought you meant that the extra node is not needed (as in nodegroup node). Read it incorrectly. I still can't get my head around the key (not very well versed with Muenchian grouping. It would be nice if you can explain a bit for me and broader audience.

Comment: No, I was talking about the `mode` `GroupC` you had in your original attempt and which I kept. As for an explanation, I have linked to the exhaustive explanation on the web, I think studying that and playing with examples should give you an understanding, the direct approach with a simple key value would work across the complete document, to only group inside a certain subtree one solution is to include the generated id of the element containing the subtree.